# Get rid of the stat bar using AR in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, augmented-reality

[image]

I'm working on an AR app and the stats bar is showing at the bottom. I want to hide it but haven't found the function that does that.

I checked the App Delegate to see if somethings was enabled but it is ok.

'''

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {
    
    var solarSystem = SolarSystem()
    var planetName:String = ""
    
    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
//        This line helps to show the points in the view
//        self.sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints]
        
        // Set the view's delegate
        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
        
        // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        
        updatePlanet()
        
        
    }
```

'''

Comment: See your view controller.

Comment: Where is your code? You more than likely are NOT hiding that, but impossible to tell without code ;)

Comment: Thanks :) for all your comments

Answer (score 0):

I was reading the documentation and I have the showStatistics active.

`sceneView.showsStatistics = false`

I just put = false.